# PLSQL table variable in packages

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package specification with record and table types declaration as follows:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PCF_USER.PC_PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2 AS

    TYPE TY_RECORD_PRODUTO IS RECORD (
            CD_PRODUTO PCF_USER.TB_PRODUTOS.CD_PRODUTO%TYPE,
            CD_PRODUTO_ORIGEM   PCF_USER.TB_PRODUTOS.CD_PRODUTO%TYPE,
            CD_EQUIPAMENTO PCF_USER.TB_EQUIPAMENTOS.CD_EQUIPAEMTNO%TYPE,
            CD_EQUIPAMENTO_ORIGEM PCF_USER.TB_EQUIPAMENTOS.CD_EQUIPAEMTNO%TYPE
          );


    TYPE TY_TB_PRODUTO_AUX IS TABLE OF TY_RECORD_PRODUTO
     INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


  PROCEDURE SP_IN_TRACKING;

END PC_PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2;
```

And the package body like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PCF_USER.PC_PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2 AS

  PROCEDURE SP_IN_TRACKING IS

    vTb_Produto_Aux PCF_USER.PC_PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2.TY_TB_PRODUTO_AUX;

  BEGIN


    -- insere na tabela auxiliar
    INSERT INTO vTb_Produto_Aux (
            CD_PRODUTO,
            CD_PRODUTO_ORIGEM,
            CD_EQUIPAMENTO,
            CD_EQUIPAMENTO_ORIGEM)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         T.ID_SLAB,
         T.CD_HEAT,
         'PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2',
         'FORNECEDOR'
        FROM PCF_USER.TB_PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2_TEMP T;




  END;

END PC_PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2;
```

I need to insert values into **vTb_Produto_Aux** table variable from a select clause.
I'm getting this error when compiling a package body:

> [Error] ORA-00942 (25: 17): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: a tabela ou view não
>   existe

What's wrong with this code? **vTb_Produto_Aux** is already declared ...

Comment: You can't do this, if you want to store the output SELECT then you have to use BULK COLLECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot `INSERT INTO` a collection  in Oracle, you may use `BULK COLLECT INTO`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     T.ID_SLAB
    ,T.CD_HEAT
    ,'PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2'
    ,'FORNECEDOR'
 BULK COLLECT
INTO vTb_Produto_Aux
FROM PCF_USER.TB_PATIO_PLACA_LTQ2_TEMP T
```